# DHT22 send email warnings

Tags: python, email, sendmail, temperature

I'm looking for a script that sends out a warning message from the raspberry pi after reaching the temperature.

Have already tried this tutorial, but I keep unfortunately too much error message, because the tutorial is so old: https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-PI-and-DHT22-temperature-and-humidity-lo/

This script worked, shows the values: https://www.piddlerintheroot.com/dht22/

But unfortunately i have no idea how to create a script to send out a mail once the temperature has been reached. Can someone help me?[image]

Comment: Way too complex problem for a single question. Some pointers: Use the `crontab` to run a wrapper script repeatedly, which checks the output of the sensor and uses `mail` to send a warning in case of abnormal values. There are tutorials online for these steps, but you'll have to write the wrapper yourself.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.